# How would I add another element to be evaluated by value to this If statement?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, key-value

How would I add another element to be evaluated by value to this statement?

```
if ($(this).val() == 1 && !$(this).data("priority1"))?
```

I'd like to use class as the selector for this new element (In this particular case class="complaint" and one of the values is "Too_small")

I've tried (both with & without brackets)

```
if ($('.complaint').val() === "Too_small" && $(this).val() == 1 && !$(this).data("priority1"))
```

I've included the function below, and a fiddle with a working example  http://jsfiddle.net/chayanyc/Dhaat/225/

```
var $priority1 = $(".priority1");
$(".features_rank1").change(function() {
    var name = $(this).data("name"); //get priority name
    if ($(this).val() == 1 && !$(this).data("priority1")) {
        //rank is 1, and not yet added to priority list
        $("<option>", {text:name, val:name}).appendTo($priority1);
        $(this).data("priority1", true); //flag as a priority item
    }
    if ($(this).data("priority1") && $(this).val() != 1) {
        //is in priority list, but now demoted
        $("option[value=" + name + "]", $priority1).remove();
        $(this).removeData("priority1"); //no longer a priority item
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't know if I'm making a mistake here but, why use "===" instead of only "=="?

Comment: @GerardDiaz `==` does type coercion, typically you always want to use `===` in Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".complaint select").val()
```

You need the value of the `select` tag under the `.complaint` class.

However, you have two element with the class of `.complaint`, so you'll need to figure out which one you want.

Comment: @Matt_Burland - I hadn't thought about that ;-) Is there a way to assign one class to the element which contains each combination (of issue and ranking) and identify all 3 elements that way? In my actual code it's all in a table, and for most of the pairs they are in the same cell

Comment: @ChayaCooper: Assigning a something unique to an element is what `id` is for. So if you gave your first span the id `shoulders` and the second `waist`, then you could do `$("#shoulders select").val()` and `$("#waist select").val()` to select each one independently.

Comment: @Matt_Burland - The code works perfectly :-D You were right about needing specify which one I want, but it's pretty cumbersome to do it with ID's since it requires a separate IF statement for each ID (and there are 20 functions like this with 15 ID's and 4 values). Can this be done with data-names and (this) statements the way it does for features_rank1? If you want to see this in context, I created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/gYtZw/22/